# Is there a way to use ScreenToWorldPoint on a secondary camera that's displayed through a UI texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, I'm using a secondary camera for my minimap, which is displayed on a raw image through a texture. I need to get the point at which you click on the map through the texture. You can zoom in and move the camera, so I can't just use the mouse position.

I also tried doing this

```
ReferenceCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x - 1350, Input.mousePosition.y - 60)); showconfirmer();
```

trying to account for how the screen is of-center, but this is tied to physical pixels and not the reference size of the ui. Should I just do some math with the screen width and Hight or is there a better solution?